# Azure functions with docker container doesn't detect functions

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-functions

We have implemented a DevOps pipeline to deploy Azure functions in a docker container that is published to a private container registry via a build pipeline. When pulling the published container to my local machine for validation, it works as expected.

After deploying the functions with this container via the deploy pipeline in DevOps, the Docker logs via the Kudu application show that the container is pulled successfully etc. So far so good.

Unfortunately, when calling the function (it has an HttpTrigger) on the deployed app, the endpoint is not found (404 response). When checking the function runtime logging, it reports that there are no functions found.

The image created is based off mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4.

I must be missing some configuration, but can't put my finger on it.

Comment: have you been able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Totally forgot to complete this question. If I remember correctly, this was related to the WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE environment variable, which should be set to false, because otherwise, the folder where the function is deployed is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering a similar issue until I set

```
WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = true
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet